# What if you could shut off the pull of gravity on your body?

Tags: magic, physics

I have an idea for a magic system where the one wielding magical power can shut off gravity for their body. However, anything on them (clothes, accessories, etc.) will still experience regular gravity.

I am having a hard time conceptualizing how this power will play out in the world. To keep it simple and hopefully get more directed help I was trying to imagine what would happen in two different scenarios:

1. What would happen if a magic user launched themselves in a catapult? Would gravity pulling on their clothes lead to a nice arc, or would they gain too much speed and splat.
2. What would happen if they were to jump straight up or at an angle? Would their momentum carry them before gravity's effect on their clothes asserted itself, and would they then pick up speed as they head back to the ground?

Comment: I think this is just a question of how the weight of their clothes would affect the person. This would depend on certain factors like the weight of the person, the force put into the jump/catapult, & the weight of their clothes. The heavier the clothes, the more they pull down on the person. The heavier the person, the longer it would take for their velocity to change. The stronger the jump/catapult, the further they go before the clothes' gravity starts to change the person's direction.

Comment: Before putting yourself in a catapult, please remember that being gravity-free doesn't make you immune to sudden changes \*Swoof\*.... In speed \*Splat\*. Oh well, who's willing to dislodge a wizard pancake from the castle walls?

Comment: Hello @SirBunks, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, please remember that asking more than one question per post is, literally, a reason to close questions ("Needs More Focus").

Comment: Magician seen heading out into space.  Last heard complaining "my pants keep falling down".

Comment: If you are interested in reading another author's take on this scenario, check out Starmind, by Spider and Jeanne Robinson. This is the exactly how the book ends.

Comment: You might also want to consider how eating & drinking affect this magical person's body. At what point does a glass of water become "part of you" such that its mass is no longer affected by gravity? Hold it in your hand - sure, it gets pulled down to the ground. What about if you hold some in your mouth without swallowing, and then spit it out again? Is it immediately part of you when you swallow? What if you vomit it back up again ... so many complications ... :P

Comment: @brhans I want to say the typical solution is that it's kind of a body shaped field. Anything inside that field, be it the apple you just ate or your artificial heart, is covered by that field. This sort of thing comes up a lot in rules regarding invisibility, teleportation, time travel, etc. The [T-800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(character)) couldn't bring clothes, but he could bring his entire skin-covered Terminator frame (and, presumably, any apples he ate. Really they should have just stuffed a gun in there. Plot holes, I tell you what.)

Comment: He should stay away from catapults. With just his legs, he can launch himself pretty well already, and when he comes down he will have about he same velocity, so his legs can absorb the landing. A catapult will launch him further, but he would come down just as fast, (minus air resistance) and it will be a hard landing.

On the other hand, a proper wing suit, or suitably modified cape, could provide enough lift (by flapping) to just fly wherever he wants to go.

Comment: So, let's break the universe (using @JamieB 's body field example). I pierce this human's body with a massive circular hose (torus). Inside the hose is a ball. Outside of the body, the ball is dragged down and drives a generator. When it gets to the low point, it enters the body, is no longer attracted by gravity, floats back up, leaves the body, and drives the generator again. Bam, thermodynamics broken, infinite power unlocked.

Comment: Have you considered that the Earth is spinning and essentially holding you in that spin? The moment you switch gravity off, the Earth lets go of you, and you move in a straight line like you're the hammer in a hammer throw. From the frame of reference of Earth's surface, that looks like you're moving upwards (and in a bit of a curve which is only noticeable after a while)

Comment: If inertia disappears with this magic, you'll instantly decelerate at 32km/s because that's how fast the earth travels relative to the sun. That's over 3,200 g. You're instantly dead.

Comment: The density of air is 1.3 kg/m³. The volume of a human is proportional to their mass: for a 77kg human, the volume is 0.077m³. Thus, your weightless magician would have the same "density" as air if they wear clothes wearing 1.3x0.077 kg = 0.1kg. If your magician wears less than 100g of clothes, then they will effectively be less dense than air and float in air just like we float in water. And if your magician is bigger than 77kg then they can wear a bit more clothes and still float.

Comment: Frame challenge: **Gravity doesn't actually "pull" you, it is not a force (!).** Gravity is a manifestation of curved space-time. Putting you outside of space-time would, in terms of common "magic" effects, also be at the base of e.g. teleportation and time travel; therefore modelling "levitation" style effects as this kind of space-time manipulation would be a powerful effect indeed. I'd say you're better off modelling "levitation" effects as *a force* that is *counteracting* the effects of gravity.

Comment: Note that your magic user would be very, very nauseous. They would have no sense of balance, and would likely start vomiting if they try to move. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otolith.

Comment: @terdon: Only a fraction of people actually become nauseous in microgravity. We know, because astronauts / "vomit comet".

Comment: @DevSolar I thought most people get at least a little nauseous, but I was thinking that a complete absence of gravity would be even worse. Possibly a wrong assumption, but it would make sense to take this into account. The magic wielder would find it very hard to move, I think. Quite apart from the obvious fact that trying to take a step would send them into the air, I would also expect serious balance issues. (This is all based on my almost total ignorance here, of course).

Comment: @terdon It's the same as being in free fall, e.g. on the ISS. You can push off of things, and would then move in that direction until you find something else to push off from, or have access to some other kind of acceleration (e.g. wings you could flap against the surrounding air, or some propulsion device). Without either air resistance will eventually stop your movement relative to the surrounding air, and you would be drifting with the wind, until the spell runs out and you fall down. ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would basically be like being on a low-gravity planet or moon.

Under normal gravity, all objects fall with identical acceleration. Heavier objects feel a larger gravitational force than light ones, but they also have more inertia to overcome. This balances out perfectly and leaves all objects with an acceleration of 1g, regardless of weight.

If the person has zero weight but their clothes do, they have essentially reduced their gravitational mass but not their inertial mass - gravity pulls down on them with the strength it pulls on perhaps a 2kg object, but that force still needs to accelerate a 70kg person. The overall result is that this person does not experience as much gravitational force as they "should" given their weight. The person exists somewhere between zero-gravity and full-gravity, commensurate with what fraction of their overall weight is made up of clothing.

They'd fly higher/further if launched by a catapult, and have a greater vertical leap and hang time when jumping. If they got naked, they'd enjoy zero gravity. If they donned a huge suit of lead armor, shutting off gravity to the body would have little overall effect.

For a typical person and outfit, clothing is <5% of the body weight, making this person experience even less than the equivalent of Pluto's gravity when shutting off their body's gravity. Even though the force holding them down is very weak, it's still more than enough to keep them from being flung from the planet due to rotational inertia.

Comment: I wonder where the cutoff is between your answer and LDutch's. Naked, you would no longer be gravitationally bound *to the planet* and would drift off (perhaps quite rapidly?). I wonder how much weight they need to wear to not basically have the earth move out from under their feet. e.g. surely a single feather wouldn't do it but a bowling ball probably would. I dunno what the math for this would be. Where's the author of XKCD when we need him.

Comment: @JamieB It would depend on your latitude - at the equator you'd get flung off but at the poles you have no tangential velocity due to rotation. Either way, it's surprising little - centripetal acceleration at the equator is about 0.3% of a g, so even a naked zero-g man would only need to carry a few tens of grams to stay on the surface at the equator in the worst case scenario.

Comment: I was thinking more of Earth's revolution around the sun, and being sent off in a straight line from there, but apparently [that's only 0.02ft/s^2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268062/why-dont-we-feel-the-subtle-speed-change-of-earths-elliptical-orbit) too, so also easy to counter!

Comment: @JamieB Indeed, if that effect weren't nearly zero as well, you'd feel your apparent weight change between night and day as you move from the "inside" of the earth's orbital path to the "outside".

Comment: note that naked at sea level, an average human body will lift up like a balloon due to buoyancy, roughly 0.7N of upward force. So wear at least underwears, or drink a glass of water.

Comment: Gravity is an acceleration, not a force.  In a vacuum, you'd still fall just as fast if gravity only applied to your clothes.  It's aerodynamic drag that will slow you down in an atmosphere.

Comment: @MontyWild Gravity is a force per mass (just like electric is a force per charge). The "it's an acceleration" model is only useful in specific situations (e.g. real-world orbital calculations) and fails to account for many aspects of everyday life (e.g. the fact you don't accelerate through the ground).

Comment: @MontyWild I think it's tricky because it would presumably be inertia vs gravity. The inertia formula would take the entire mass -- body and all things carried, while the gravity formula would only use the mass of carried objects. So if you carry a single feather, it's the inertia of your body trying to continue in a straight line (potentially off the planet, depending on where you stand) versus the gravity of the feather pulling you towards the planet.

Comment: @MontyWild: In real life, and thus pretty much everything we've established, mass is invariably tied to gravitational attraction. In OP's example, we're dealing with a mass that is gravitationally ignored. Inertia still applies, therefore the gravity-ignorant human body will act as a braking force on the gravity-affected clothing, in the same sense that a large ballast will reduce a rocket's acceleration. A clothed human with gravity turned on and a clothed human with gravity turned off will **not** fall identically, even in a vacuum, because their analogous "thrust" is different.

Answer (score 16):

The first thing you'd want to consider is centrifugal force. If gravity isn't holding you to the ground, then the rotation of the earth would throw you off. The centrifugal force is roughly 1% of your weight, so if you were on the equator and you weighed 200lbs, you'd need to wear at least 2 lbs worth of clothing to stay on the ground.

A weird bit would be that, if you aren't at the equator, the centrifugal pull would pull you at an angle, so even with clothing, you'd have to lean against it to keep from being pulled towards the equator.

When falling from a great height, your terminal velocity would be a lot lower. Put your clothing on a cardboard cut-out and drop it off of the roof to see how much. You would be able to control how you fluttered around the same way sky-divers do, but you'd need to manage your wardrobe if you didn't want to fall feet-first.

**update:** Nuclear Hogie pointed out that the force of gravity on your clothing would be divided into your mass plus the clothing's mass. This is hugely important, because it means that the overall effect would be equivalent to around 1% of normal gravity. Even wearing full field plate armor, you'd be experiencing 1/3rd gravity.

If gravity pulling on your clothing alone were analogous to pushing a person, gravity on your clothing pulling on your whole body would be analogous to pushing a person in a car. This supports his low-gravity hypothesis.

**2nd update:** John pointed out buoyancy, which, at sea level, would (very) roughly be equal to your weight divided by 773, or between 1/8th to 1/7th that of centrifugal force. Thanks, John!

When being launched, wind resistance would be fighting against your mass, not your weight. You'd still slow down due to wind resistance, but I suspect that a pumpkin chunkin' trebuchet could throw you miles away. If your clothing wasn't adequate to counter centrifugal force, you would never come down.

It occurs to me that, if you could come up with a squirrel suit that weighed less than the centrifugal weight offset, you could turn the power on to get altitude, then turn it off and use the squirrel suit to get some velocity.

Oh, as a final point, if you wore light-weight wings (and were reasonably fit), you could definitely fly, but slowly.

Comment: That squirrel suit idea is pretty cool! Thanks!

Comment: don't forget buoyancy force, you are essentially a vacuum airship. 0.012544 N of lift per liter.

Comment: @John Sorry I have a limited knowledge of buoyancy, how would density play a factor, as the density of the magic user is still the same, it's just their weight would be zero.

Comment: @SirBunks, buoyancy of an object is equal to it's weight minus the weight of whatever it's displacing. So a liter of water weighs a kilogram. If you have a 1-liter block that weighs 1/4 kilograms, it's buoyancy in water is -3/4 kilograms.

Answer (score 5):

Gravity is what keeps everybody and everything existing on Earth on the planet.

Without gravity, each body, conforming to Newton's First Law, would continue in a straight line until a force acted on it. This means that if your person is naked while activating their power, they would immediately fly off along a tangent to Earth's surface at the same velocity of the surface in that moment.
This means they would slowly drift up, while the rest of the planet would keep revolving around its center.

The above would be true for a short time, but then also the motion around the Sun would start to become noticeable, and later on also the motion around the center of the Galaxy. By that point, however, the person would be already dead of suffocation due to the exposure to the vacuum of space.

If instead the person wore clothes, as stated by Nuclear Hoagie, they would get a little weight from their clothes and would manage to avoid death.

Comment: Wouldn't the person be catapulted with extreme violence upwards, by the new sudden buyoance they acquired? While they aren't suscetible to gravity, the air around them is. Wouldn't then the air rushing beneath them force them upwards like, _fast_?

Comment: @Mermaker, a cubic meter of air (way more than a human body volume) has a mass of 1 kg, not that much lifting

Comment: But that assumes all the bodies are under effect of the same gravity, which isn't the case. The air is being pulled down, the body isn't, and it is easier for the body to rise (since the air is thinner above it) than it is to stay put. I think we have more interactions here than we're giving thought to...

Comment: @Mermaker A cubic meter of 0kg vacuum enclosed in 1kg of clothing has a density of 1kg/m^3, roughly the same as air. So long as the net density of the person and their clothes is greater than that of air, they are not buoyant. A helium balloon is a reasonable reference for buoyancy, too, since filling a rigid balloon with vacuum instead of helium actually wouldn't make it float much better.

Answer (score 4):

**You might need to tie a rope to the poor mage**

> What would happen if a magic user launched themselves in a catapult? Would gravities pulling on their clothes lead to a nice arc, or would they gain too much speed and splat.

I made an error with the first version of my answer. The mage still has mass, but not weight.

The last thing, the very last thing that you want to do, is put that poor mage into a catapult. Why?

*There's no longer an escape velocity other than the force needed to overcome air resistance.*

Without the mass of the mage, all that's holding that poor devil to the ground is the weight of his/her clothes. The energy needed to move a couple of pounds of clothes to escape velocity is a LOT lower than what would be needed to move the entire mage.

Now, honestly, no, a catapult can't put the mage into orbit. ("Blue. No, yelloAAAAAAAAAGHHHHHH!") The clothing would need to reach 11 km/s and a quick Google search indicates the best "muzzle" speed of a trebuchet (so much better than a catapult...) is only 0.45km/s.

But, still, the poor schmuck might need to care about the mountain range in the distance.

...With the exception of air resistance, which will slow him down. Eventually.

*BTW: Considering the popularity of extreme sports like bungee jumping, I'm a bit surprised that someone hasn't put an electronically-controlled parachute on someone and launched them out of a trebuchet. Honestly, I'd bet people would line up to hand you $100 to be thrown from a trebuchet. GPS-enabled electronics to release first streamers to slow the <s>victim</s> participant followed by the release of the parachute. If anybody does it, I thought of it first. You owe me dinner and movie for two.*

**Muscles... on the other hand...**

> What would happen if they were to jump straight up or at an angle? Would their momentum carry them before [gravity's] effects on their clothes asserted itself, and would they then pick up speed as they head back to the ground?

This is a different matter because we're dealing with much less energy than a catapult. The body's muscles, *which have grown accustomed to the weight of the body.* Take away that weight, and the muscles can do a lot more work!

Think about it this way: you get a job moving 50# bags of cement all day. After 3-4 months of work (and a lot of sore muscles), the job gets easier. Your body's muscles have grown accustomed to moving *your weight plus the weight of the cement.* You might not have noticed, but it's actually easier to move yourself around the dance floor at night thanks to the stronger muscles.

The situation is the same. Rather than not moving 50# bags of cement, you're not moving, let's say, 200# worth of person. But that person's muscles are conditioned to moving 200# worth of person! You bet, you'd be able to proverbially (and, to a degree, realistically) leap those tall buildings in a single bound!

*This concept was adopted by Edgar Rice Burroughs for his Barsoom series of books. John Carter, having grown up on Earth, found himself on the much weaker gravity of Mars. At the time of writing, neither authors nor the public knew Mars' gravity was weaker, but didn't really understand what that meant. So no one blinked twice when John Carter was able to leap 50-100 feet into the air.... Of course he could! Muscles conditioned to 1G were suddenly in 1/3 the gravity.*

How high could the mage jump? We can use the following equation if we know how high the mage could jump *before the spell.*

$$\text{Height}_\text{peak} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\text{velocity}_\text{takeoff}^2}{9.81}\right)$$

Use the equation the first time to solve for *velocity<sub>takeoff</sub>,* then use it a second time.... Here's where things get a bit tricky. You see, we're cheating in that the number 9.81 reflects the acceleration of Earth's gravity. I'll leave it up to the user to reverse engineer this to deal with mass (e.g., the original mass of the mage + the mass of the clothes, then solving for just the mass of the clothes). Instead, we can get a rough estimate of how wonderful this spell is by simply changing 9.81... to 1.0. That's basically 10X the jump height — and you can rationalize more simply because that's a very, very conservative simplification.

**That all seems a bit counter-intuitive**

I know. The catapult is putting the same energy into throwing a rock and throwing the weightless mage. Logic would say that the mage would travel further. In a vacuum, that would be true, but over the distance a catapulted rock is intended to travel and the speed that's involved, air resistance becomes a big deal!

Compared to the shorter span and lower energy push of muscles, air resistance has a much lower effect on the result. That's why the mage can jump further, but would have trouble with catapults.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about eliminating _inertia_, just the pull of gravity.  So if flung from a catapult, surely their inertia would mean air resistance was negligible.

Comment: jumping would be like pushing with legs against a swimming pool wall when doing a flip turn, assuming this water has air density.

Comment: @jdunlop I thought about that: the idea that the weight might be zero but the mass is still there.... That difference is obvious in the weightless vacuum of space. But how to simulate that in outer space? The air isn't just producing resistance, it's still under the influence of gravity - so when you impact an air molecule/atom, you're fighting both the molecule/atom's inertia (its mass) and the influence of gravity on it. Since the mage is no longer similarly benefited by gravity, that makes air resistance more influential, doesn't it?

Comment: @JBH - it'd be more like something neutrally buoyant moving through water.  Buoyancy means that the object in the water is effectively weightless (the sum of the forces acting upon it are zero), but still has to deal with water resistance.  The water resistance, however, is not any greater or lesser from the lack of influence of gravity on the object moving through it.

Comment: You're suggesting that the person becomes massless, but that's not what OP asked. He specified "shutting off gravity." If you impart motion, it will still have the same inertia, and air resistance would still need to whittle away at it like it normally does. You just wouldn't have the limitless force of gravity pulling it against that drag.

Comment: @RobertRapplean That's what JD and I are discussing. Does a planet have an escape velocity beyond the need to overcome air resistance if the effect of gravity is zero? Oh... that's interesting.

Comment: @jdunlop All good points, JD. I've changed the answer.

Comment: @JBH, on that one, no. Escape velocity is specifically the velocity required to overcome gravity. Unless you're standing on one of the poles, the movement of the air would literally launch you off of the planet.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YcpZT8YHfc (Regarding the trebuchet idea.)

Comment: @RobertRapplean Weight of the mage's clothes. The force of wind would need to propel the clothes at 11 km/s. The strongest wind recorded (a tornado) was only 0.13 km/s. Now, if the mage were standing there buck nekid.... the only thing that could stop the mage would be air resistance - but that would stop the mage somewhere in the sky. That would be... um... inconvenient as the only way down is to be pushed down by the wind/rain/snow or to cancel the spell. I wonder how much force would be required to push a weightless 1m ball through the air into orbit?

Comment: @RobertRapplean However, your point does underscore the impracticality of the spell. I don't think clothes would be enough weight to keep you upright, much less unaffected by the world around you. The rocking of a boat, wind, a friend jauntily slapping you on the back. And unless you brace yourself against something, how do you put your clothes on? The more I think about it, the more I suspect this would make a hilarious scene in a book, ("I tried my new spell today.... maybe I'll use it against my enemies instead!") but it's looking like it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @JBH, 11km/s means that the mage has no hope of ever returning, and that isn't going to happen. The mage is moving at .46km/s just by standing on the surface. LEO orbital velocity is 7.5km/s, but that still presumes gravity. You might want to look into SpinLaunch to see what it takes to make that happen. Without rocketry for redirection, any trajectory you threw the thing into would inevitably re-enter.

Comment: The only danger to the mage from the catapult is the launch acceleration.  Escape velocity is irrelevant--drag will bring him to atmospheric velocity long before he's outside the atmosphere.  (Naked, he still dies due to centrifugal force and buoyancy unless he's very skilled at switching it on and off so as to land without going splat.)

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of good answers already, I'll just add a bit more intuition to the mix. You can imagine your weightless wizard like an air balloon, filled with air and a little bit of helium. A normal air balloon is slightly heavier than air; in your case you want it to be slightly lighter than air (as if it was filled with vacuum), so - a balloon which is slightly lighter than air and rises slowly up. Well, when naked anyway. Clothing would keep them grounded.

Answer (score 1):

## You need a lever, not an on/off toggle

Sure, maybe the apprentices can only change their gravity full-blast, but surely experienced mages are able to subtly shift their interactions with gravity? That would give you more wiggle room to get a variety of effects.

More directly to your question, though, you can basically think of the described scenario as if the mage only weighs as much as his clothing and accessories. His body is still subject to drag, though, making him like a kite or parachute- Lots of surface area, relatively little mass.

##### Flight Scenarios

Throwing a kite or parachute from a catapult wouldn't go very far. Turning gravity down or off on a person **already flying** through the air would cause them to **speed up** proportionally, to follow the law of conservation of momentum. (Their top speed would be limited by drag, as that [increases exponentially with velocity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=drag%20force&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22drag%20force%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Formula%22%7D).) Becoming heavier again mid-flight would cause them to slow to **beneath their initial speed**, as some momentum was lost earlier due to the increased drag.

I'm reminded of the main character from Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn, Era 2, who can "store" some/all of his weight, weighing less for a time, then draw upon that store to weigh as much as a freight train at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Let it solve as a physic puzzle here:

- For the mage himself, we have 2 mass, him and his belongings.
- The magic spell removed the force of gravity for him, but not his acceleration

Then:

We can compute:

$m_{belongings} * g = [m_{belongings} + m_{mage}] * acceleration$

The acceleration on the mage will then be:

$acceleration = \frac{m_{belongings}}{m_{belongings} + m_{mage}} * g$

What it means is that the mage will simply act as if his acceleration is divided by the ratio of his belongings and his own mass (considering his belongings are an order of magnitude lighter than him).

If he was naked, his acceleration would be zero (he will continue to travel at the same speed as he was before until he hits something). This would mean that if he pushed on something (like jumping), he won't stop until the air resistance would cancel his speed (which might take a **huge** time at slow speed). He won't be called back to the ground (until it rains a lot)

As soon as he has some belonging, the same movement will act like in a linear combination of how the belonging would proceed and what I described above.
The heavier the belonging, the closer to the usual behavior.

Some note here: Even if he jumped with all his strength, and appears to fly.
If he hits something, he will hit with his actual speed and mass.
His speed might be low (due to low acceleration), but his mass is not changed, so his moment of inertia ($mass * velocity$) is still high.

Its a bit like if you were hit by a lead ball and a plastic ping pong ball of the same volume going at the same speed. The effect of the lead ball will be a lot more painful than the ping pong ball.

### To answer the catapult question:

The catapult transfers/converts mechanical energy to kinetic energy.
An ideal catapult would thus give all its mechanical energy to the *bullet*.

Since the kinetic energy isn't dependent on the acceleration and thus, the force of gravity, the effect on the mage would be the same as if he was subject to gravity (he would get the same speed with or without the spell).

As soon as he's ejected from the catapult, you are back to the first law of Newton, except that this time, you've to account for another additional force, the air resistance (called drag force) which is proportional to the surface area of the mage and his speed (and not his mass).

This term will append on the force of gravity of the belonging too. It would slow down the mage's speed as fast as if he was submitted to gravity, but his parabola back to the ground will be a lot longer since it would be like if only the belongings were catapulted, with a parachute the size of the mage.

To give a nice example, he would behave like a badminton's shuttlecock, until he hits the ground. When he does, he'd create the same crater as  a 100kg lead ball coming at the same speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reminded of "The Billiard Ball" by Asimov, where the twist was that any object which was completely isolated from gravity perforce moved at lightspeed.

The problem I have is: if isolated from all external influences, in what direction would it move?